# Downloading multiple files or rolling back if anything fails

Tags: android, download

I'm creating an Android app that needs to download a set of images and audio files in order to work properly. Those files will be updated on the server from time to time. On startup, the app will check for updated files and download them.

My concern: The updates/downloads of those files must be completed in an atomic fashion, meaning that the update is successful only if all files have been downloaded. If one file failed to download (reason being poor internet connection, insufficient storage space on the phone, etc), the update should be rolled back.

I feel that implementing something like that from scratch could be a pretty big task, so I first wanted to ask if there's already a library/module, or at least a best practice for implementing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel that implementing something like that from scratch could be a pretty big task.

I disagree:

Your app can creat a temporary private folder (i.e. -tmp-update-20190321_122800) and download all files into this folder.

After all downlads finished without error the app can replace the original files.

So instead of searching for a transaction-multi-filie-download-lib you can use any android-download-lib and you must know how to copy/move/delete files.